# How to override property "sites.email.membership.reply.body" in liferay

Tags: hook, liferay, liferay-6

I want override the following properties in my `portal-ext.properties`:

```
sites.email.membership.reply.subject=com/liferay/portlet/sites/dependencies/email_membership_reply_subject.tmpl
sites.email.membership.reply.body=com/liferay/portlet/sites/dependencies/email_membership_reply_body.tmpl
sites.email.membership.request.subject=com/liferay/portlet/sites/dependencies/email_membership_request_subject.tmpl
sites.email.membership.request.body=com/liferay/portlet/sites/dependencies/email_membership_request_body.tmpl
```

to something like this:

```
sites.email.membership.reply.subject=com/krishna/email_membership_reply_subject.tmpl
sites.email.membership.reply.body=com/krishna/email_membership_reply_body.tmpl
sites.email.membership.request.subject=com/krishna/email_membership_request_subject.tmpl
sites.email.membership.request.body=com/krishna/email_membership_request_body.tmpl
```

I have done this in `EXT`, i.e. I have created the package: `ext-impl/src/com/krishna/` in `EXT-plugin` and it works fine, but I am not able to do this in a `hook` or `portlet`. Why? Because its giving me exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to open resource in class loader com/krishna/email_membership_request_subject.tmpl
```

So, my question: **Is there a way to do it in hook or portlet or only EXT can be used?**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done only in an EXT plugin. Because of the following two reasons:

1. Hooks can be advantageous to override few properties/services but not all. This particular property is not supported by hooks.
2. This is definitely not possible with portlets, as you already are facing class loading issues. As `portal-impl.jar` is located inside the `ROOT/WEB-INF/lib` of liferay and your portlet doesn't have access to it.

So EXT plugin is the only way.

Comment: Do you have a list of the properties supported by hooks? and also by overriding this property it doesn't mean I am trying to access `portal-impl.jar`. I understand that the code to load these `*.tmpl` files is in `portal-impl.jar` but is there not a way I can ask liferay to look into my specific plugin?

Comment: You can find out through Liferay IDE, it will allow you to see most of the properties that you can override when you are creating hooks. As far as I know there is no other method to include templates from your plugin.